# Alternate trouble removing events using js function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

There's a simple (I think so) function to add and remove events.
It's working well in adding but never in removing.

I commented in the code others attempts.

```js
  var wrnOn = function() { document.getElementById("accuort").style.display = "block"; }
var wrnOff = function() { document.getElementById("accuort").style.display = "none"; }

function toggleIcon( /*id, imgUrlOn, imgUrlOff*/ ) {

  if (emptyFormChecking()) {
    document.getElementById('advan').src = "img/filter.png";
    document.getElementById("accuort").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('submits').removeEventListener("mouseover", wrnOn, true);
    document.getElementById('submits').removeEventListener("mouseout", wrnOff, true);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('advan').src = "img/activefilter.png";
    let x = getOffset(document.getElementById('submits')).left;
    let y = getOffset(document.getElementById('submits')).top;
    document.getElementById('accuort').style.left = (x + 61) + "px";
    document.getElementById('accuort').style.top = (y + 32) + "px";
    document.getElementById('submits').addEventListener("mouseover", wrnOn, true);
    document.getElementById('submits').addEventListener("mouseout", wrnOff, true);
  }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Each time your `toggleIcon()` function is called, the handler functions are created as brand new functions. The `removeEventListener()` API expects the functions to be the *exact match* of the previously-registered event handlers.

Comment: Forgive me but I'm not a javascript expert. And therefore? what would be the solution? create the event outside the function? or is it possible to mark it so that the remoteEventListener () can recognize it?

Comment: no, the first hypothesis don't work ...

Comment: If the functions are declared *outside* of `toggleIcon()`, and they never change, then your code will (probably) work. The issue is that in general two distinct objects are never `==` to each other. If you keep referring to the same exact two functions, then you won't have that problem.

Comment: as I wrote I have already tried but it still doesn't work.   (moreover I updated the code in my question)

Comment: The basic problem is `var wrOn = function ...`.  Each time `toggleIcon()` is called, that declaration results in the creation of a brand new function object.  It will *never* be exactly the same as any other function object, so passing it to `removeListener` cannot possibly ever work.

Comment: You edited it so the declarations of `wrnOn` and `wrnOff` are now outside `toggleIcon()` but didn’t say anything about it. Is it still not working after making that change? Is that what your code actually looks like?

Comment: yes in fact what I applied is a trick that don't change the matter: I moved the statements out but they are still instantiated in the same way ... I'll try to work around the hitch - rather than activating and deactivating the event for the object - creating or destroying a brand new object each time (with built-in listeners) using dom

Answer (score 0):

Solved
*(oh damn it!  I'm ashamed  ... it was so simple!)*

```html
function toggleIcon() {
 if (emptyFormChecking()) {
  document.getElementById('advan').src = "img/filter.png";
  onOff(false);
 }
 else { 
  document.getElementById('advan').src = "img/activefilter.png";
  let x = getOffset(document.getElementById('submits')).left;
  let y = getOffset(document.getElementById('submits')).top;
  document.getElementById('accuort').style.left = (x+61)+"px";
  document.getElementById('accuort').style.top = (y+32)+"px";
  onOff(true);
 }
}
```

and upstream

```js
var wrnOn = function() { document.getElementById("accuort").style.display = "block"; }
var wrnOff = function() { document.getElementById("accuort").style.display = "none"; }
function onOff(flag) {
 if (flag) {
  document.getElementById('submits').addEventListener("mouseover", wrnOn, true);
  document.getElementById('submits').addEventListener("mouseout", wrnOff, true);
 }
 else {
  document.getElementById("accuort").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('submits').removeEventListener("mouseover", wrnOn, true);
  document.getElementById('submits').removeEventListener("mouseout", wrnOff, true);
 }
}
```

thank you all!